# find tables in SQL that are indirectly connected

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, foreign-keys

Let's put an example:
a table with primary key: animal_id (1....1000), animal type (cat, dog...).
then 12309123 tables more, and another table with primary key: breed_id, breed_name, whatever_else.

Somewhere I should have a table that connects breed_id and animal_id. How could I create a query that helps me to find such thing?

Comment: The answer depends on which database you're actually using - their data dictionary tables all have different names.

Comment: `12309123 tables more` eh?

Comment: you need a solution for all three databases??

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful code a while back to solve this issue in SQL server

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, 
t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
```

This should give you all the columns, which you can then filter as appropriate with the WHERE clause.